# Conditional rendering from a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'd like to conditionally render a React component like this:

`parent.ts`

```
   ...
   <Parent>
     <Child/>
   <Parent>
   ...
```

`child.ts`

```
   ...
   return (someBoolean && <Component/>)
   ...
```

I get a TypeScript error in `child.ts` that `Its return type 'false | Element' is not a valid JSX element.`

I want the conditional to be in `child.ts`, because it is used in other places as well, not just `parent.ts`. What's the appropriate way to do this? Would I have to settle for a ternary or if/else?

Comment: You could instead write `some ? <Comp /> : null` or `<>{some && <Comp />}</>`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking `someBoolean ? <Component /> : null` as alternative, but was hoping there was some other way

Comment: `some ? <Comp /> : null` is the proper way to do it. It's what React recommends and for good reason, it's not prone to short circuiting bugs where you could throw any falsey value into the JSX.

Comment: `someBoolean ? <Component /> : null` is the canonical way to handle this that I've seen and used. Otherwise within JSX interpolation you can use `&&` like @rn3w's answer

Answer (score 2):

i think you lost `{ to evaluate }`

```
return (<>
          {someBoolean && <Component/>}
        </>)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience using hundreds of thousands of ternaries in React, I would recommend using it like

```
const A = () => {
  // Never in a form where it's easy to miss the ternary symbols
  // Leads to bugs...
  return (superUnderTip >= Math.pow(UserService.count(), 2)) ? 
  <ProviderTrainsFully lights={{hgih: 33}} rest={"too many null"} /> : null;

  // Always in this form so your brain can super easily scan for the
  // test and the output component.
  return (superUnderTip >= Math.pow(UserService.count(), 2))
    ? <ProviderTrainsFully lights={{hgih: 33}} rest={"too many null"} />
    : null;
    
  // Never in a nested ternary -- make child components for additional
  // conditional rendering.
}
```